# Are there problems with implementing a listener in a View subclass?

Tags: java, android, android-view, onclicklistener

I need to subclass TextView to have it hold some additional data for me.  I'm placing these new View objects into a ListView using a custom ListAdapter.

I have an action I want to perform `onClick()`, and it is the same action for all elements of the ListView, based on the additional data.

**Would this definition, have any downsides or cause any problems?**

```
public class UserTextView extends TextView implements OnClickListener {

    public int userId;

    public UserTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);

        this.setClickable(true);
        this.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

I would expect that the code in my `onClick()` implementation wouldn't actually be copied, but would only exist once in memory and be called with the specific `UserTextView`'s data. So I don't expect extra memory usage.  And in fact, not having an extra Class and Object (anonymous or not) might improve performance (though not in a real, meaningful way).

If needed, the `setOnClickListener()` method could be invoked to change the Listener if I needed different behavior for a specific object.

It just seems to fit well into what I need:

1. A TextView that can hold extra data (userId)
2. A TextView class that will have the same default behavior
3. Can be created and managed easily by a ListAdapter

I just feel that I have never seen this done this way, and am suspicious that there is something I'm missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know everything not static is within memory once for each instance of a class. This means that by this design your code is nice and clean but looking and memory usage it does not make a difference.

Comment: Well depending on what you mean "once for each instance of a class" this could mean that the memory footprint of each instance has to include the `onClick()` code.  But my understanding is that all methods are held like they are static (once per class), but that the call stack works to make it aware of the **instance** it should be run against (hence `this`)

Comment: I also understand it the same way, sorry for my bad explanation. Only variables are per instance because they have a state. Methods do not (should not) have a state. Therefor they are only loaded once into memory.